# How to circularly fade an image to alpha in compositing?

Tags: transparency, compositing-nodes, masking

I'm trying to circularly fade an image into transparency in the blender compositor.

My approach was to use an *Ellipse Mask* in combination with the *Set Alpha* node, so that the picture becomes more and more transparent towards the edges.

[image: Node Setup i've used.]

Output of the *Set Alpha* Node:
[image: The render result of the 'Set Alpha' Node.]

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as the center turns black where it should be transparent. (The original image has a transparent background.)

What am I doing wrong?

This behavior occured in Blender 2.91.2 and 2.83.5 (on Linux).

---

In the example used, I try to get rid of the shadow that protrudes over the edge.

The effect I like to achieve would look something like this:

[image: Expectation of render result.]

---

EDIT:

Unfortunately, if the *Ellipse Mask* is inverted the outer area turns black (should be transparent).

[image: Node Setup of the suggestion.]

Output of the *Set Alpha* Node:
[image: The render result of the 'Set Alpha' Node.]

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, but couldn't you just put an Invert node between the glare and the Set Alpha?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Thanks for your suggestion. I've reworked the question to address it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your node setup is ignoring the existing Alpha channel. Instead of overwriting it, you need to multiply it with your mask.

I used the `Separate RGBA` node to extract the current Alpha value, and a Math node to multiply the two values:

[image: Node setup]